# How can I make a htaccess redirect without keeping the path?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am really confused... I have searched and experimented, but can't seem to get anything to work. So I gave up and asked here :)

How can I redirect /subfolder to root, but every page inside the subfolder should be redirected to root?

/subfolder redirects to root
/subfolder/another-folder redirects to root (not root/another-folder)

Thanks.

Comment: so you want to redirect `/subfolder/foobar` to `/foobar` ?

Comment: I was not clear in my writing. I want /subfolder and any variation of /subfolder/path or /subfolder/path-path/path to redirect to /

The only redirect I have managed to make right now is the one you mentioned /subfolder/path redirects to /path and subfolder/path-path redirects to /path-path. I want all variations of /subfolder to just redirect to home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect requests from `/subfolder` to `/` (to the root folder) ,you can use the following Rule in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subfolder/(.*)\sHTTP  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /%1 [NE,L,R]
```

The RewriteRule above will redirect any request from `/subfolder/foobar` to `/foobar` but  you will get a 404 not found error since `/foobar` doesn't exist in your `/root` fodder.

To solve this ,you need a RewriteRule to internally rewrite requests from `/root` to `/subfolder` .The following rule will Internally map `http://example.com/foobar` to `http://example.com/subfolder/foobar` .The redirection from root to the subfolder is invisible.

Add the following right bellow the `subfolder` to `/root` redirection rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

EDIT :

My apologies. I misread your question. If you want to redirect your `/subfolder` requests to just  the root folder ,try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subfolder/(.*)\sHTTP  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it does not work. I have added all of this now, and this is where I am at:

domain.com/subfolder --> domain.com (correct)
domain.com/subfolder/page --> domain.com/page (incorrect)

I want domain.com/subfolder/page to redirect to just domain.com

Comment: Thank for the edit. I am not getting it to work. It's kind of weird. Putting this in the .htaccess should redirect it before the request even hits the Wordpress-installation on the server, right?

I am on a Litespeed-server, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @TASan This should work if you put this before your wordpress rules .